# How to reduce padding in css? (section class)

Tags: html, css

How can I edit the padding of this class in css

```
 <section class="wpb_row main_row  no-seperator" style="padding-top:70px; padding-bottom:70px;">
```

I tried this code but it doesn't work:

```
wpb_row.main_row.no-seperator
{padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:0px;}
```

Comment: why have the padding in the <section> tag to begin with if you want to remove it?

Comment: You've missed a dot at the CSS selector. It is `wpb_row.main_row.no-seperator`, should be `.wpb_row.main_row.no-seperator`

Comment: @dbrree I needed help because I'm customizing a theme

Comment: @fredix11, I just mean why have it in the `section` tag as `style="padding-top:70px; padding-bottom:70px;` , just to change it in the CSS? I just wanted to get an understanding of that. The reason being, you may need to add `!important` to your CSS as I see someone already added as the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The css is tied to that particular element through the html style-tag. You'll have to edit that or use `!important`.

```
.wpb_row.main_row.no-seperator
{padding-top:0px !important; padding-bottom:0px !important;}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the `.` at the start of your css:

```
.wpb_row.main_row.no-seperator
{padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:0px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

If im not mistaking, youre missing a "." at the beginning of your statement. The answer should read:

```
.wpb_row.main_row.no-seperator
{padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:0px;} !!This piece is extremely 
important!!
```